# Refactoring Code in Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, regex, sublime-text-3

Currently I do this with `Find All` (<kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> `old_var`, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> `new_var`), but this replaces words in my comments and strings.

A comment in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22592410/5289570) suggested the [PyRefactor plugin](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PyRefactor) which requires [rope](https://github.com/python-rope/rope). These tools seem to have defaults that are too heavy-handed for my purposes. I just want to refactor variable names in stand-alone python scripts with Sublime Text 3.

So in a script like

```
# Where did my hat go?
hat = 0
print(hat)
print("hat")
```

The `hat` variable (not in strings nor comments) can be replaced with something else at the touch of a hotkey. No need for a special project folder/configuration, and nothing changed across multiple files. Unfortunately, <kbd>Find All</kbd> `hat -> llama` does...

```
# Where did my llama go?
llama = 0
print(llama)
print("llama")
```

EDIT:

I appreciate @Toto's regex solution, but I'm not fluent in that yet and would like a method that works more consistently and is easier to remember. Is there a plugin (or can I write one?) that identifies all the globally defined and stated variables (arguments in function calls, etc), and allows for a simple Find and Replace?

Comment: You can likely use a regex to see if the line starts with #

Comment: Have you thought about using an IDE that makes refactoring like this much easier? I used to be loyal to Sublime, until I discovered JetBrains IDEs.

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find: `(?:^(?<!#).*\K|(<?!"))\bhat\b(?!")`
- Replace: `llama`
- *check Regular expression*
- *check Whole word*
- *check Wrap*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:
    ^       : beginning of line
    (?<!#)  : negative lookbehind, zero-length assertion that makes sure we don't have # before
    .*      : 0 or more any character
    \k      : forget all we have seen until this position
  |         : OR
    (?<!")  : negative lookbehind, zero-length assertion that makes sure we don't have " before
)
\b      : word boundary to not match chat, remove it if you want to match chat also
hat     : literally
\b      : word boundary to not match hats, remove it if you want to match hats also
(?!")   : negative lookahead, zero-length assertion that makes sure we don't have " after
```

**Given:**

```
# Where did my hat go?
hat = 0
chat = 0
print(hat)
print("hat")
print(chat)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
# Where did my hat go?
llama = 0
chat = 0
print(llama)
print("hat")
print(chat)
```

**Before:**

[image]
**After:**

[image]

Comment: what about `"red hat"`, or `"red " + hat`? Both will be replaced but they shouldn't

Comment: @MátéJuhász: `"red hat"` is not replaced and `"red " + hat` becomes `"red " + llama` isn't that wanted?

Comment: ok, that's clever, what about `"red hat and gloves"`?

Comment: @MátéJuhász: Of course, it will not work in this case :( for such case the regex will become unreadable. This is showing the limit of regex when parsing non regular language.

Comment: Can always count on regex to the rescue. Unfortunately this case doesn't work either: `"hat ate the hw"` becomes `"llama ate the hw"`.

Comment: @Wassadamo: True it doesn't work for any string like `"blah hat blah"`. I don't know if it exists a plugin that does the job. I think the best way is writing a proper parser.